# How to make just one ExpansionPanel, in an ExpansionPanelList different to the others? flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As the question suggests I have an ExpansionPanelList, one ExpansionPanel (the last one or the 7th one) should have 2 additional buttons, but how can I add them just in this one last panel & not in all the others as well?

This is the code of my whole Expansion panel, as Im not sure where you have to add the behaviour, but guessing in the body of the ExpansionPanel (close to line 40):

```
    class ExpansionList extends StatefulWidget {
  final Info info;

  const ExpansionList({
    Key key,
    this.info,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ExpansionListState createState() => _ExpansionListState();
}

class _ExpansionListState extends State<ExpansionList> {
  Widget _buildListPanel() {
    return Container(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          cardColor: Color(0xffDDBEA9),
        ),
        child: ExpansionPanelList(
          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
            setState(() {
              infos[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
            });
          },
          children: infos.map<ExpansionPanel>((Info info) {
            return ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: !isExpanded
                        ? Text(
                            info.headerValue,
                          ) //code if above statement is true
                        : Text(
                            info.headerValue,
                            textScaleFactor: 1.3,
                            style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                  );
                },
                body: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffFFE8D6),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ListView.separated(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0,),
                          itemCount: info.expandedValueData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CheckboxListTile(
                                title: Text(info.expandedValueData[index].title,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: info.expandedValueData[index]
                                                .completed
                                            ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                            : null)),
                                value: info.expandedValueData[index].completed,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
// Here you toggle the checked item state
                                    infos.firstWhere(
                                        (currentInfo) => info == currentInfo)
                                      ..expandedValueData[index].completed =
                                          value;
                                  });
                                });
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        Row(children: [
                          SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.16),
                          Text("Abschnitt bis zum Neustart löschen"),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.11),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                infos.removeWhere(
                                    (currentInfo) => info == currentInfo);
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        ]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                isExpanded: info.isExpanded);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildListPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Just add a field (if you already do not have one) in the info object that will allow you to change the widget that is inflated based on that field.
For example

```
...
children: infos.map<ExpansionPanel>((Info info) {
  return ExpansionPanel(
    headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
      return info.type == TYPE_A ? TypeAWidgetHeader(info) : TypeBWidgetHeader(info);
    body: info.type == TYPE_A ? TypeAWidgetBody(info) : TypeBWidgetBody(info);
...
```

Comment: I have 3 questions, 1.when I don't want to change the header can I just skip this line: "return info.type == TYPE_A ? TypeAWidgetHeader(info) : TypeBWidgetHeader(info);", 2. If I understand correctly TYPE_A holds the info  in my case whether the tile that should be build is a normal or the "custom" Panel, but how can I define TYPE_A so it has the info that the custom Panel is on the 7th position? 3.And lastly Do I have to make a new body class for the regular & for the custom Panel?

Comment: Your code is missing some closures, which would result in an error. Try correcting it so that it's clear for everyone.

Comment: Through a bit of testing I figured all out, thank you! :)

Comment: hi @Nikita sorry, yesterday I was a bit in a hurry and couldn't write a more detailed answer. I just saw your message. I'm glad you managed to solve it